# Implementation of toString() for Tuples/Product/case classes

Tags: scala, tuples, tostring

I want to customize a case class `toString()` method.

```
case class MyCaseClass {
  // stuff ..
 override def toString() {
   // mostly same as default but I want to omit some of the fields
}
```

My first look was into the Product and Product extended by all case classes . But turns out they are traits that do not contain the `toString()` .

So where in the scala library class hierarchy for case classes (/Products) is the `toString()` located?

Comment: Unless I'm missing what do you want to do, you can just override it as you do to any class (exactly as you do above).

Comment: @roterl By blindly overriding we lose the goodness of the auto generated case class toString() that provides the values of all the Tuple entries.  That is why the intent is to *customize* it not just *replace* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

toString is automatically generated by the scala compiler. The only thing you can customize is the productPrefix

Here is a simple case class

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
```

And its toString method (using :javap -c Foo in the scala console)

```
  public java.lang.String toString();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #63                 // Field scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime$.MODULE$:Lscala/runtime/ScalaRunTime$;
       3: aload_0
       4: invokevirtual #85                 // Method scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime$._toString:(Lscala/Product;)Ljava/lang/String;
       7: areturn
```

So as you can see, toString is implemented by calling `scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(this)`.

If you just want to change the name of your class, you can override productPrefix:

```
case class FooImpl(a: Int, b: Int) {
  override def productPrefix = "Foo"
}

scala> FooImpl(1,2)
res1: FooImpl = Foo(1,2)
```

If you want to do something more complex, like omitting some fields, you will have to just override toString

```
case class Foo3(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) {
  override def toString = "Foo3" + (a, b)
}

scala> Foo3(1,2,3)
res2: Foo3 = Foo(1,2)
```

Another alternative is to have multiple parameter lists.

```
scala> case class Foo3(a: Int, b: Int)(c: Int)
defined class Foo3

scala> Foo3(1,2)(3)
res3: Foo3 = Foo3(1,2) // only the arguments of the first argument list are printed

scala> Foo3(1,2)(3).productArity
res4: Int = 2 // product arity is number of arguments of the first argument list
```

Comment: Thx, that's not the "answer" I was *hoping* for .. but it's *accurate* so am awarding.

Comment: I think that usually, if you want to customize case classes too much (omit fields from toString, equality, hashCode etc.), you don't want case classes in the first place. One thing you *can* do is to use multiple parameter lists: `case class Foo3(a: Int, b: Int)(c: Int)`. Only the fields in the first parameter list will be considered for toString, equals and hashCode.

Comment: Just saw your updates.  Using the (a,b) tuple is  nice approach. In any case I just customized the toString manually.  The multi paramater lists may be useful for other more serious use cases: thx for that insight.

Answer (score 1):

**CODE:**

```scala
object CaseTest {

  trait TSV extends Product {  // #1
    override def toString:String = productIterator.mkString("\t")  // #2
  }

  case class A(name:String, age:Int) extends TSV // #3

  case class B(a:A, b:Boolean) extends TSV

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val a = A("Me", 23)
    val b = B(A("Other", 45), b = true)
    println(a)
    println(b)
  }  
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Me|23
Other|45|true
```

**PROCESS:**

1. Create a Trait that extends **Product**
2. Override the **toString** method in the new Trait
3. Extends all your **case classes** from the new Trait

You don't really need to extends from **Product**, but it will give you access to a lot of the functionality of the case classes like the **productIterator**.

Comment: Hi RojoSam: your idea technically works . But adding entire new classes feels a bit heavy.